# Writing to a file also appending

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i've run into a problem where: My code creates a file with headers, writes data to it. And then when i run it for a second time it overwrites the data, which it should but start a new line. Also, what does delimiter mean?

```
#Intro
import csv

headers=["Name","Age","Year Group"]
with open("Details.csv","a" and "w") as i:
      w=csv.writer(i,delimiter=",")
     w.writerow(headers)
     print("Welcome User, to my Topics Quiz!\n------------------------------
      ---------\nYou can choose from 3 different topics:\n  • History\n  • Music\n  • 
     Computer Science\n---------------------------------------")
     #Storing: User's name, age and year group
     print("Before we start, we need to register an account.")
     User=input("Enter your name:\n")
     Age=input("Enter your age:\n")
     Year=input("Enter your year group:\n")

    details=[User,Age,Year]
    w.writerow(details)
with open("UserPass.csv","a" and "w") as Userpass:
    w=csv.writer(Userpass,delimiter=",")
    headers=["Username","Password"]
    w.writerow(headers)
    NewUser=(User[:3]+Age)
    print("Great! Your username is set to: {}".format(NewUser))
    Pass=input("Enter a password for your account:\n")
    userpass=[NewUser,Pass]
    w.writerow(userpass)
```

So the code will write out the data when i want it to add.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"a" and "w"` means just `"w"`; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation.  I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with this syntax but if you just want to append to an existing file just use `"a"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're mode is only `"w"`:

```
>>> "a" and "w" == "w"
True
```

Instead use only `"a"`.

Comment: Agreed, i've tried this but it creates multiple headers in the csv file.[link](https://gyazo.com/e4b68d78b5a97c23db52bee6d22fc384)

Answer (score 0):

**a** is enough for the open mode.

**Append: "a"** has **Write: "w"** in its definition. When you say you want to append it means you want to write at the end... So don't use them together.

**delimiter** means separator which most of the times refers to some characters like comma, space, dot, etc.

Comment: I run into the problem, the headers are created multiple times [Link](https://gyazo.com/e4b68d78b5a97c23db52bee6d22fc384)

Comment: Don't write the headers every time... Just append the information you need.

Comment: Yes, but if i run it multiple time it does regardless. So i need a way to add the data without it adding another set of headers and appending the data on a second attempt.

Comment: You can check if the file already exists. If it's there don't write the header. So before the first part do this... Also you can check if header is already in the first line of the file. safer

Comment: Nice idea, how do you propose i check if there is a header already?

Comment: First read a row from the file and then check if it's equal with ["Name","Age","Year Group"] or any header that you've already wrote in the file.

Comment: Thank you, but I still come to a point where two headers are being made. I though differently and that it would work. [Link](https://gyazo.com/ebf60c0b5c3906c584e5f35b3e60c178)

Comment: How do you run this code? The thing is it is possible that you read the file to put the second input **before the first write to the file has been finished**.

Comment: To make it more clear: here in this code you request the input for one time and write them to the files one time. How do you proceed the call for several inputs?

Comment: I run the code again. No while loop. Just restart the code

Comment: add f.close at the end

Comment: Nothing still :( [Code](https://gyazo.com/fad0c3e70dbfc0cdb60d7059e31256ac) [CSV](https://gyazo.com/eda6cad6f11328efe3fbc86b51a22120)

Comment: You have to add smth like this in the code. What you read from the file is this: "Name,Age,Year Group\r\n". **headerline = "Name,Age,Year Group\r\n"
    line = Details.readline()
    if line != headerline:** . Another issue is that you have to read one line, don't use readlines in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to append to an existing .csv file you need to either:

- skip writing the header if the file already exists, (check with `os.path.exists()` **before** opening it) **or**
- open the  file in read mode & read the file into memory first, (as a list of lists), close it then add the new row to the data and then *over*write the whole thing, *including headers*, over the original, *(this does let you do things like sorting the rows)*.

As others have said your file open mode should be one of:

- "r"  = **R**ead Text
- "rb" = **R**ead **B**inary
- "w"  = *Over***W**rite Text
- "wb" = *Over***W**rite **B**inary
- "a"  = **A**ppend Text
- "ab" = **A**ppend **B**inary

The delimiter specifies what separates the fields in the .csv file.

As an aside you should **never** store passwords - instead you should store a hash of the password and when the user next enters a password calculate the same hash and compare it with the stored hash. Something like:

```
import hashlib
import getpass

pswd = getpass.getpass()
userpass = hashlib.sha256(pswd.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Would you be able to help write the code. For i dont understand how i would do so. Also its for school work.

Answer (score 0):

As for the term *delimiter*, remember that CSV stands for Comma Seperated Values. *Delimiter* means seperator; CSV uses a comma (",") as its seperator or delimiter, but the python module `csv` gives you the option to specify a different delimiter, such as a tab character (`"\t"`), etc.

As for the file operations, you could check if the file is blank. If it is, write the headers. Then (always) append the data. Something like this:

```
# open the file for appending (the "a"). Create it if it doesn't exist (the "+")
with open(filename, "a+") as f:
  w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")

  # only write the headers if the file is blank (i.e. the first time the program runs)
  if f.read() == "":
    w.writerows[headers]

  # get `details` from the user.
  # ...

  # the data always gets appended 
  w.writerows(details)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very nice, idea also with another. But I've tried many different variations of your way. But still stumps me to the conclusion that 2 headers are still being made. [Link](https://gyazo.com/ebf60c0b5c3906c584e5f35b3e60c178)